# Clojure: how to load a dynamic value?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and facing a problem.

```
(def db-config {:dbtype "sqlite" :dbname "demo.db"})

(def db
  (jdbc/get-datasource db-config))

(defn execute [sql]
  (jdbc/execute! db sql
             {:return-keys true}))
```

I have a web page which user can change db name.

The problem is how to load the db with dynamic db name?

example, there are 5 database files, "1.db", "2.db"..."5.db". After user click 5.db in web page. I should execute sql with 5.db.

I can do it in Python with a simple way. but I don't know the Clojure way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `db` value an argument of the `execute` function:

```
(defn ->db [db-name]
  (jdbc/get-datasource (assoc {:dbtype "sqlite"} :dbname db-name)))
  
(defn execute [db sql]
  (jdbc/execute! db sql
             {:return-keys true}))

(execute (->db "foo.db") sql)
```